# qt creator incorrectly processes header files includes from include directory

Tags: c++, include, qt-creator, header-files

I have include dir in my project which contains cpp header files:

```
./projectName/include/**/*.hpp
```

and src dir with cpp files:

```
./projectName/src/**/*.cpp
```

When i create .pro file like that:

```
SOURCES += \
src/dir1/name1.cpp \
...
src/dirN/nameN.cpp

HEADERS += \
include/dir1/name1.hpp \
...
include/dirN/nameN.hpp
```

include preprocessor instruction highlighted as containing error:

```
#include "dir1/name1.hpp"
```

But in my cmake build configuration file such includes work well.

How to make them work in qt creator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the larger path `#include "include/dir1/name1.hpp"`

Or add the absolute path to the .pro file in INCLUDEPATH variable, like
`INCLUDEPATH += "C:\path\to\your\stuff\include"`

Comment: this changes would break build system process, consider directory structure  fixed because build process has more priority than editor.